# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::edit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::edit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

```
public function edit ($id , User $user) {
  $user = $user->find($id);
  return view('admin.user.edit',compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: This issue as it is currently written has nothing to do with javascript, jquery or css... Please use the correct tags in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you url is something like: `site.com/profile/1`

And if this url corespond the this edit function

```
// you can just ask from your model to get the user that has id: 1
// which is coming from Eloquent model.
public function edit (User $user) {
   return view('admin.user.edit',compact('user'));
}
```

If your url is not like this also function wouldn't work tho

Answer (score -1):

You should edit you method to the following:

```
public function edit (int $id , UserRepository $repo) {
  $user = $repo->find($id);
  return view('admin.user.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

And make sure at the top of your file you have appropriate namespaces declared.